# std::cout and printf are dropping chars out C++

Tags: c++, c, json, networking, encoding

I'm downloading a file from a url using socket.h and when I try to output the contents of the buffer I get only parts of it.
Here's the  to file, a basic json file. `http://82.80.47.90/WarningMessages/alerts.json`

Related code -

```
 size_t MAX_DATA_LENGTH = 50001;
 char bufIn[MAX_DATA_LENGTH];
 dataLength = recv(sockfd, bufIn, MAX_DATA_LENGTH-1, 0);
 bufIn[dataLength] = '\0';
 std::cout  << "client: received data length " <<  dataLength << std::endl << bufIn;
```

My console output when I run it -

> HTTP for oref.org.il:
>
> Sent. client: received data length 524
>   HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Cache-Control: max-age=4  Content-Length: 174  Content-Type:application/json
>   Last-Modified: Tue, 15 Jul 2014  08:43:22 GMT
>   Accept-Ranges: bytes
>   ETag: W/"6bad3d68a0cf1:2d5"
>   Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
>   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>    Date: Tue, 15 Jul 2014 08:44:45 GMT
>   Set-Cookie: cookiesession1=KI4GAQVLKVW4JFN90R6B9GAANOO8HAYR;Path=/
>
> > ��{

While... When I sniff the packets the output is -

> {  "id" : "1405424602778", "title" : "    ", "data" : [] }

Or :

```
0000   ff fe 7b 00 20 00 0d 00 0a 00 22 00 69 00 64 00  ..{. .....".i.d.
0010   22 00 20 00 3a 00 20 00 22 00 31 00 34 00 30 00  ". .:. .".1.4.0.
0020   35 00 34 00 32 00 34 00 36 00 30 00 32 00 37 00  5.4.2.4.6.0.2.7.
0030   37 00 38 00 22 00 2c 00 0d 00 0a 00 22 00 74 00  7.8.".,.....".t.
0040   69 00 74 00 6c 00 65 00 22 00 20 00 3a 00 20 00  i.t.l.e.". .:. .
0050   22 00 e4 05 d9 05 e7 05 d5 05 d3 05 20 00 d4 05  "........... ...
0060   e2 05 d5 05 e8 05 e3 05 20 00 d4 05 ea 05 e8 05  ........ .......
0070   e2 05 d4 05 20 00 d1 05 de 05 e8 05 d7 05 d1 05  .... ...........
0080   20 00 22 00 2c 00 0d 00 0a 00 22 00 64 00 61 00   .".,.....".d.a.
0090   74 00 61 00 22 00 20 00 3a 00 20 00 5b 00 5d 00  t.a.". .:. .[.].
00a0   0d 00 0a 00 7d 00 0d 00 0a 00 0d 00 0a 00        ....}.........
```

I really would appriciate your help. I've tried to change encoding but the encoding is UTF-8 so there's no point of changing it.
Thanks!

Comment: The encoding in your dump seems to be UTF16-LE, not UTF-8.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I've from a guy that the site uses UTF-16 but when I've tried to check the encoding using  a PHP function it said that it's UTF-8. I'll try to convert it using iconv, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're sending `cout` a `const char*` to `bufIn`, so the only way `cout` can judge it's length is to find the first NUL byte: your data is not ASCII so it hits the "ff fe 7b 00" bybtes and stops its output.  If you want to avoid that you can either force NULs to be sent to the terminal using `cout.write(bufIn, dataLength)`, or iterate over the data printing the `isprint()`-able characters normally and printing say `\`*octal value* or whatever other notation you like.

Further, TCP is a byte stream protocol, which means whatever data you try to read can be delivered to you in smaller sections with the only necessary granularity at the byte level.  If you recv once and only get part of the data, you should loop and recv again until you get all you expect/need (or EOF/disconnect/error).  It's your job to reassemble that data or otherwise handle it in some way suiting your needs.  Some API functions do let you block until a specific number of bytes have been retrieved (or EOF/disconnect/error), but that's not the normal behaviour.  Read the man page for `recv` and look at some examples, but summarily:

```
size_t MAX_DATA_LENGTH = 50001;
char bufIn[MAX_DATA_LENGTH];
size_t position = 0;
size_t dataLength;
while ((dataLength = recv(sockfd, bufIn + position, MAX_DATA_LENGTH-position-1, 0)) > 0)
    position += dataLength;
dataLength = position;
bufIn[dataLength] = '\0';
```

Not the cleanest code, but that's the general idea.

Comment: Well, using wireshark and comparing to dataLength, I've noticed that I do get only 525 bytes while the data length as listed on Wireshark is 579. So what is your suggestion? Thanks, maybe the 54 bytes are the headers or something?

Comment: @Yohonatan: all you have to do is keep recv-ing until there's nothing more to get... some indicative (untested) code edited in that should set you on the right track.

Comment: Well, using the cout.write just solved it. The only problem now is that it changes the letters to ����� ����� ����� �����

Comment: Exactly how they appear depends on your terminal program, but that's why I'm saying you'll probably want to iterate over the characters one at a time, using `if (std::isprint(c)) std::cout << c; else std::cout << '\\' << std::oct << std::setw(3) << std::setfill('0') << (int)c;` or similar.